# I can't get a button to do two things

Tags: c#, button

Basically i want a button to create a .cnf file and run a .bat file one after the other.

Code 1: (Button 1) (Not Full code)

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\"+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".cnf";

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("localityName_default        =" + (localityTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("0.organizationName_default  =" + (organisationTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("organizationalUnitName_default  =" + (organisationalUnitTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("commonName_default          =" + (domainListBox.SelectedItem));
        sw.WriteLine("emailAddress_default            =" + (emailTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

Code 2: (Button2)

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string path = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\"+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".bat";

    //This Saves The Users Data into a text file
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(@"@cd\OpenSSL-Win64\bin");
        sw.WriteLine(@"@dir");
        sw.WriteLine(@"openssl genrsa -out "+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".key 2048");
        sw.WriteLine("");
        sw.WriteLine(@"@cd\openSSL-Win64\bin");
        sw.WriteLine(@"@dir");
        sw.WriteLine(@"openssl req -new -nodes -key "+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".key -out "+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".csr -config "+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".cnf -batch");
    }

    Process GenKey = new Process();
    GenKey.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\"+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".bat";
    GenKey.Start();
}
```

The First Piece of code creates a .cnf file and the second piece of code runs a .bat file. This works perfectly but you have to press two buttons, one after another. I want it to be able to work with a single press of a button.

Comment: The place where you assign your button event (Usually in Designer.cs) just add the event to the button you want to do both with `Button.Click += EVENTHANDLER` - You can simply change the secondary button's click event to the first button.

Comment: Move the code from `button7_Click` to `button6_Click`? If your question is not about pressing Ctrl-X and Ctrl-V, you may want to clarify your question.

Comment: @nvoigt i tried that.

Comment: @CallumGlennBrankin ...and the problem was?

Comment: @nvoigt the problem was that the path names for both of the destination paths were the same, so i changed one of them to "path2"

Comment: @CallumGlennBrankin That does not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegates

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
```

Modify this in your Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

`button6_Click` and `button7_Click` are methods that are called when you click the button (they handle the click event of the button control). If you don't need two separate buttons at all, you can instead create methods that aren't linked to your button controls:

```
private void CreateConfig()
{
    string path = @"C:\OpenSSL-Win64\bin\"+(serverListBox.SelectedItem)+".cnf";

    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path))
    {
        sw.WriteLine("localityName_default        ="+(localityTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("0.organizationName_default  ="+(organisationTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("organizationalUnitName_default  =" +(organisationalUnitTextBox.Text));
        sw.WriteLine("commonName_default          =" +(domainListBox.SelectedItem));
        sw.WriteLine("emailAddress_default            ="+(emailTextBox.Text));
    }
}
```

And similar for you batch file creation. You can then call both inside one of the button click handlers:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateConfig();
    CreateBatchFile();
}
```